# Django Debug toolbar - Prototypejs version

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, frameworks, prototypejs

I am a big fan of [Django Debug Toolbar](http://github.com/dcramer/django-debug-toolbar/tree/master) But what happened is it totally has got Jquery framework being used for all its UI richness. But my application uses Prototypejs. So browser is actually getting confused to execute(or not executing) a couple of methods written by me. So how do I get pass this?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this doc
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 1):

I've made efforts to fix this in my branch:
http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/

I've done only basic testing with Prototype and jQuery (and mootools and jQuery) in the debug toolbar and how I'm making them to not conflict.  More use cases and testing would make this better, so please try it out and let me know if this helps.